# Which server logging solution is less processor consuming among Kafka, Fluentd and Logstash?

Tags: logging, logstash, apache-kafka, distributed, fluentd

I have a distributed logging system to monitor load-balanced server entities. It is basic for me, that the server does not invest a lot of processor time in the logging process, allowing the application to run with the maximum resources possible.

It would be nice to know, which of those alternatives is "cheaper" in terms of processor time or, in case, to be recommended any other solution for this matter.

Comment: Why did you rule out the Elastic-provided lightweight shipper, filebeat?

Comment: @Alain thanks for that, I missed it in my research. I might add it to the question since I think it might be useful for the reply. Is it really lightweight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Kafka **is not** a log collector. It's a distributed message queue and can work with log collectors like Fluentd and Logstash both as consumers and producers.

Instead of opinions, let's put some numbers.

1. CPU Usage: This depends on how much filtering and data processing you do on the client-side using Fluentd and/or Logstash. If you do minimal processing, both can process 10,000+ messages per second. Both can take advantage of multiple CPUs (http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/in_multiprocess, for example)
2. Memory: Fluentd uses about 40MB of memory and Logstash uses about 100MB of memory. If this is too much, Logstash has Beats and Fluentd as Fluentd Forwarders (https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-forwarder).

Comment: Most log collectors are based on distributed message architectures, and of course they handle it by managing queues. Thanks for your help, but it's not what I look for.

Comment: @Karlos No, most log collectors aren't based on distributed messaging architecture at all. None of Logstash, Fluentd, syslog-ng and syslog is distributed. They are _deployed_ in a distributed environment, but that's different from software being distributed. Also, it's really, really important that you get the difference between log collection and log ingestion.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use just a simple lightweight [rsyslog](https://www.rsyslog.com/), [syslog-ng](https://www.syslog-ng.com/) or [syslogd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/syslogd).

Depends on which technologies you'd like to use?

Comment: Yes, my previous approach to this solution was using syslogd. The reason because I stopped using it is basically the message filtering and forwarding. It was a hard config issue to send properly filtered messages or adding tags to them based on the logged message. Did you manage a good message filtering based for example on logged fields using any of the lightweight solutions you mention?

Comment: Sure, I recommend `rsyslog`: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/filters.html

Comment: BTW I wouldn't use a shipper that's written in Ruby :) In fact I wouldn't use a shipper that initially takes more than 20MB of memory. Once you start ingesting data, amount of used RAM will depend on your memory (and file system) buffering configuration.

Comment: I like Flume, but that choice will depend on the amount of data you need to ingest, since it's definitely not lightweight (requires Java JVM) and it's a bit harder to set up (e.g. requires protobuf) and generally intended for "big data" (its "primary" destination is Hadoop).

Answer (score 1):

We are using Flume to collect logs and ship to Kafka - it is very low on CPU usage, and memory-wise- it is up to you how much buffering you want to do.
You can also write your own Flume interceptor if you need custom parsing/routing of data.

Comment: It looks great Marina, I will have a look at it, for now this answer and the one by @Marko are the most promising for me.

Answer (score -1):

fluentd and logstash all have processor cost, better to not run them on your application server. For, kafka, since it is only its client be running on your server, it should be cheaper, but then the stability of your server depends on the stability of the kafka servers.

A better solution might be to log to files and install a cheaper log collector/forwarder to forward the log files to another server for running any log parsers with.

Comment: With all due respect, Kafka is not a log collector. What you are talking about is a producer library for Kafka, which is really not software but a piece of code that the user has to write.

Comment: @Kiyoto, Kafka is not a traditional log collector, but there are many people , even big companies, now use it to collect logs, so that you could subscribe to kafka for parsing in a very flexible way.

Comment: Let me clarify again. My definition of a data collector is a piece of software that encompasses the logic of acquiring and parsing log data without external logic. Kafka does NOT do this. For Kafka, this is the job of Kafka producers, and that role is assumed by a variety of software, including Logstash, Fluentd, Heka, syslog-ng, etc. Mixing Kafka up with actual data collectors is a very dangerous mindset since data collectors and message queues have vastly different requirements and operational characteristics (For example, Kafka will never have any feature related to parsing).

Comment: The owner's question is more about solving the problem of logging and log forwarding rather than parsing. Is it really an issue if Kafka could solve the problem, but it is not a pure log collector? Let's focus more on solving problem rather than definitions.